# Displaying a String letter by letter "animation" in a JLabel?

Tags: java, string, swing, loops

Is there any way to show a phrase, per se, "Welcome!", letter by letter with a very small delay between them? I would provide what I've tried but I haven't even come close to barely working, nothing worth mentioning. I suppose I would have to use a loop containing a scanner, yes? Any help appreciated, thanks:)

Comment: jlabel tag? are you using swing or console? if console just with a thread sleep, you can... if it's swing you should look for `swing timers`

Comment: You could start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Swing. I couldn't gather much from the Concurrency in Swing link, sorry/:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Caveats**

Swing is a single threaded framework, that is, all updates and modifications to the UI are expected to be executed from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Equally, any operation which blocks the EDT will prevent it from processing (amongst other things), paint updates, meaning that the UI won't be updated until the block is removed.

**Example**

There are a few ways you could achieve this.  You could use a `SwingWorker` and while it would be a good learning exercise, it would probably be a little over kill for this problem.

Instead, you can use a `javax.swing.Timer`.  This allows you to schedule callbacks at regular intervals, these callbacks are executed within the context of the EDT which will you allow you to update the UI safely.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class AnimatedLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnimatedLabel();
    }

    public AnimatedLabel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setSize(100, 100);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private String text = "Hello";
        private JLabel label;
        private int charIndex = 0;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel();
            add(label);
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String labelText = label.getText();
                    labelText += text.charAt(charIndex);
                    label.setText(labelText);
                    charIndex++;
                    if (charIndex >= text.length()) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

**Update from comments**

The main problem is your `text` value is wrapped in `<html>`

```
static String text = "<html>Welcome! I will ask simple, two-answer questions, and you will answer them. Simple as that. </html>";
```

And then you apply it to your label...

```
final JLabel centerText = new JLabel(text);
```

So when the timer runs, it ends up append the text again...

```
"<html>Welcome! I will ask simple, two-answer questions, and you will answer them. Simple as that. </html><html>Welcome! I will ask simple, two-answer questions, and you will answer them. Simple as that. </html>"
```

Which is invalid, because everything after the `</html>` will be ignored.

Instead, remove the `<html>` tags from the `text`

```
static String text = "Welcome! I will ask simple, two-answer questions, and you will answer them. Simple as that.";
```

And set the initial text of the label with `<html>`

```
final JLabel centerText = new JLabel("<html>);
```

Don't worry, Swing will take care of it...

Comment: Thanks, it works on its own, but I can't seem to make it work in my code. There are no errors, and I hope I have implemented it correctly, but I'm not quite sure - http://pastebin.com/C4bYxZrW

Comment: The problem is, you've already set the text of the label, which is using `<html>`, so you are append `<html>` text to `<html>` text, which produces an invalid result.  Instead, you should change you `centerText` label to be initialised `final JLabel centerText = new JLabel("<html>")` as.  You should remove `<html>` from the start of the `text` variable.  I would also recommend that you avoid `null` layouts

Comment: I'm really sorry that I'm slow at getting this, I don't learn very well due to... Well, mental issues at this point in life. I'm confused as to what the value of the JLabel would be, then. `"<html>"`? Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: I see... Again, terribly sorry for the inconvenience. It is working now, thank you:)